# Subdivision surface modifier creates pinching at corners

Tags: modeling, vertices, subdivision-surface

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image] 
[mesh1.blend](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1PP_oMIabaikYOClEePlwxdv-51wbmfCt/view?usp=sharing) 
I've only been 3D modelling for a few days now, so this may just be a newbie mistake:

However, because this model is for use in a game I am trying to stay away from proximity loops for performance reasons. Instead, I have used edge creases to maintain the structure of the model. It has led to certain vertices not being affected by the subsurf modifier, causing undesirable lighting at high subsurf levels.

Manually moving each point in a bit seems kind of sloppy but I'm not too sure what the best way to go about this is.

If any more information is needed I'll give what I can, thanks in advance :)

Comment: I don't get what's the desired result (smooth arc? quad-like window?) but if you're really modelling for a game then no subsurf. Model in mid-poly to create enough geometry for main forms but still not highpoly and export. Also please inclde images into the question body and not 3rd party service

Comment: Ah sorry first time posting, but yeah the desired result is exactly how it is at the moment, but without that weird pinch at the vertex.

Comment: Another solution would be to give the surrounding edges also weight. The two edges that are also connected to the corner should solve your problem without adding additional edgeloops. Or use a bevel modifier.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, unfortunately adding crease weight to those edges just creates a visible hard line from the vertex to the outer edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is in your topology. I suggest you do something like this :

[image]

[image]

The idea is that you have to place the basis of topology which the subdivision modifier will follow :

[image]

If you do that correctly, you will have the right result.

Also, be aware that using mean crease really should remain as a temporary solution. It's handy for prototyping mostly; because it's fast and doesn't require more work, but it doesn't provide any precise control on the obtained shape and geometry.
I've seen some people using it to create quickly and roughly a basic shape. Once they are happy with the shape and volumes, they add a new object on top of it, add some shrinkwrap modifiers, snapping tools, and they to the final model and focus on topology and shape refining.

Comment: I concur with this. My hope was, that the Auto-Smooth Property might fix it, but, alas, no. Topology change it is.

Comment: AFAIK, Blender's Auto-smooth only changes the normals' orientations.

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, appreciate it :)

Answer (score 1):

That usually seems to be the case for edge weighting instead of using holding edges. I've had this problem in other programs too (modo). Just add another loop between those windows to give it something to hang on to.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate the response! I've tried implementing your solution but I'm not sure I've done it correctly as the issue persists. I've added a picture showing where I placed the loop, is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

Just to make sure, try running "Remove Doubles". This will remove points that are in the same (or close to) location. They give similar artifacts to what you are seeing.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it but unfortunately there were no doubles in the mesh.

Comment: Can you upload the file?

Comment: I've added a google drive link, thanks for taking a look!